# Why the Vuetify <v-select> component don't display my data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I use `Vuetify`, I want display one data array in `<v-select>` component.
In my real app I use `async` data. My app working in my local server and in my test server, but when I deploy in other app (in the working numeric environment) the  component not working anymore.

I supposed it's because data are `async` and I tried to modify the data. I tried with local data and the `<v-select>` not work either with local data. My code :

```
      <v-select :items="airData"
                item-text="name"
                item-value="id"
                :label="$t('pages.Home.form.repositories.label.name')"
                v-model="selected"
                :error-messages="repositoryErrors"
                color="valid"
                :attach="true"
      />
...
data () {
    return {
      selected: 1,
      airData: [
        {
          name: 'repository 1',
          id: 1
        }, {
          name: 'repository 2',
          id: 2
        }, {
          name: 'repository 3',
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

...and the vuetify display "No data available".

[image: Screenshot of the v-select component]

Thx for your help !

Comment: Did you try a lean version with just :items property?

Comment: @MatheusValenza yes, I did. I tried with `:items` with attributs `text` and `value` instead of `name` and `id`, as in the documentation.

Comment: What is `:label="$t('pages.Home.form.repositories.label.name')"` ? If I remove that, everything is working fine.

Comment: @Toodoo I tried to delete the label, but the v-menu stil doesn't work. I have se same problem with the datepicker (it also use v-menu).

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen where the issue reproduce ?

Comment: If you remove `:label="$t('pages.Home.form.repositories.label.name')"` it still does not work ?

Comment: @Toodoo No, It doesn't work... For `<v-select>` it's the `no-data` div that appears, for the <v-date-picker> the `v-date-picker-header` displayed but no `v-date-picker-table`